# Java my own .jar/.dll storage

Tags: java, classpath

I want to create a own single folder which contains all the .dlls, .jars, resources.

We have a lot of self-services, the idea is after downloading from the repo, all projects should work correct without any "human being" help..

So how i can add Java`s searching directory for .dll/.jar files (default are ../lib/ext and ../bin)?

Comment: Isn't this what Nexus is a smarter solution for? At least the JAR files part...

Comment: Maybe we`ll use it in future.. But now we need easier solution..

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a folder say "Resources" and keep all files in it. You can set your jars in class path.
Your class path entry like below:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="Resources/*.jar"/>
```

check in all resources to your repository, whenever check out the code you get all resources and class path will become valid.

If you have IVY, try it. You no need to keep all jar files with your code. (Ignore if you don't have.)

Comment: Of course, all files are in the same directory. And what about native(.dll)?